# Marcar propriedades alteradas em vez de usar o tradicional Update é uma boa pratica? (Ef core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Tenho optado por usar o `update` desta forma:

```
_context.Entry(site).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
_context.Entry(site).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
_context.Entry(site).Property(x => x.Description).IsModified = true;
_context.Entry(site).Property(x => x.Link).IsModified = true;
```

Marco como `Unchanged` toda entidade e depois marco as propriedades que possivelmente foram modificas que ao meu ver isso Gera mais desempenho e evita erros, mas isso é uma boa pratica ou é perda de tempo?

Comment: vai depender do contexto, se for um entidade, não há necessidade, mas, como não temos um contexto real fica complicado dar uma resposta. Se puder editar a sua pergunta e melhorar com um exemplo claro.

Answer (score 1):

Eu prefiro usar o IsModified na entidade toda, não acho que seja uma pratica ruim e também não vejo problema na forma que você utilizou.